# Does database require block storage always?

Tags: storage

I was reading the difference between block, file and object storage and I read somewhere that database require the underlying storage to be block storage. Is this true? Can I not install a database on a system that has file storage?

Comment: *Where* did you read this?

Comment: Well, in the end regular file system is also using blocks to store the data - because that's the way how the harddisk is physically structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true. Many DBMSes today (eg Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL) use file storage by default, although some (eg Oracle) can also use block storage.